# Trying to understand the for loop in this JavaScript duplicate removing algorithm

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

First off, here's the algorithm:

```js
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length;) {
        if (nums[i] === nums[i + 1]) {
            nums.splice(i, 1)
        }
        else i++
    }
    return nums
};
```

It takes in a sorted array of numbers and removes any duplicates to return the original array modified to only include unique numbers.

My question mainly concerns the usage of the for loop. In this for loop we are omitting the third statement and instead are incrementing `i` in the `else` condition.

How does the loop know to check the next index of `nums` if the `if` condition is fulfilled? Ie. if we never hit `else`, how is `i` incremented? Is it even incremented? I understand this may have something to do with the fact that we are splicing (therefore shortening) the nums array in the if condition but I am having a hard time fully grasping why the loop does not end as soon as the if statement is fulfilled once.

Comment: `splice`  changes the length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
nums.splice(i, 1)
```

this removes 1 item from the array at index `i`. For example, if `i` is 2, and the current array is

```
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]
```

then, right after that `splice` occurs, the array becomes

```
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]
       ^^ REMOVED: Array mutates to
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The item that used to be at index `i + 1` is now at index `i`, so the next iteration of the `for` loop should not increment `i`.

If you *did* increment `i` regardless, then every item that comes immediately after a removed item would be skipped, and not iterated over at all:

```js
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] === nums[i + 1]) {
            nums.splice(i, 1)
        }
    }
    return nums
};

console.log(removeDuplicates([0, 1, 1, 1]));
```

Still, this style of code is very confusing: when an object changes *while you're iterating over it*, it can be pretty unclear what the logic being implemented in accomplishes. Better to deduplicate via a Set:

```js
var removeDuplicates = nums => [...new Set(nums)];

console.log(removeDuplicates([0, 1, 1, 1]));
```

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for the reply. So do we 'stay inside' the for loop after the splice until i < nums.length? Ie. is the loop still active until i is incremented to be equal to nums.length?

Comment: Yes, the loop will continue until the condition `i < nums.length` is false, no matter how `i` or the array length happens to change; that condition is re-checked at the start of each iteration.

Comment: Done! Meant to do it last night but it said I had to wait a certain period of time before doing so. Thanks a lot again!